# Kivy calculator application

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, frameworks, kivy

Trying to build a simple calculator with the kivy framework.

This is in my main.py file

```
class Calculator(AnchorLayout):

inputs = ObjectProperty(None)

def backward(self, express):
    if express:
        self.display.text = express[:-1]

def show(self):
    self.inputs.text = self.inputs.text + self.text

def calculate(self, express):
    if not express: return

    try:
        self.display.text = str( eval(express) )
    except Exception:
        self.display.text = 'error'


class CalculatorApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Calculator()


CalculatorApp().run()
```

and in my kivy file instead of doing:

```
Button:
            text: '9'
            on_press: input_string.text += self.text
```

i want to use the show function that i defined in my main.py

```
Button:    
            text: '7'
            on_press: root.show()
```

but i get an AttributeError: Calculator object has no attribute 'text'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have this line in the show method of `Calculator`:

```
self.inputs.text = self.inputs.text + self.text
```

This refers to self.text, but the code you've given never sets this attribute for the Calculator, therefore you get the given error: `Calculator object has no attribute 'text'`